# Discord.py send message from non-async function

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I have a program that looks like this:

```
import things
import discord


def on_thing_happen (variable):
    get_info()
    do thing()
    # This is where I want to send a message in Discord
```

For reasons, the rest of my code cannot work in an async function.

Is there any way to do this? I cannot use an async def.

Comment: Does your use-case allow the use of a webhook?

Comment: Possibly, but I've never used webhooks before, so I wouldn't know what I was doing.

Comment: Upon further inspection, no, a webhook wouldn't work. It needs to be a proper bot.

Comment: discord.py is a an async library, and while it is "sort of" possible to run a `send` event from a sync function it can cause some weird behavior.  I'm not sure what blocking code you are trying to run, but it will likely be better to have a standard async function that runs your blocking function in [an asyncio executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) and you can use `await send` as normal

Comment: How would it be "sort of possible"?

Comment: [asyncio.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) will run a coroutine, you can try that but I've seen it create more problems than it solves.

Comment: Doing it within discord.py might involve using `asyncio.run` or a similar function in your sync code. Whereby it will call an async function that has the logic for sending. Since you do not have Context, you will have to fetch the relevant channel by ID and call send on it inside the function. But the whole process sounds convoluted to me. bot.get_channel should run in a sync context so all you'd need to do is pass the object to your async function. But if you wish to do the entire process synchronously, you will have an easier time making direct API calls.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to run `send` without first running the `bot.run` because your bot needs to log in and connect to the websockets to communicate with the discord API. Could you be more specific about exactly what you need to do? One option would be to have your bot run in another process and listen for messages on some queue, then use that to decide when to send messages.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
import things
import discord

client = discord.Client()

def on_thing_happen (variable):
    get_info()
    do thing()
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL ID) #replace with channel id of text channel in discord
    client.loop.create_task(channel.send('Message'))
```

So instead of `await channel.send('message')` it is `client.loop.create_task(channel.send('message')`

I hope this works!

Comment: You're a savior mate! Thank you so much